# 504 Gateway Timeout : Deploying Ruby on Rails 6 on AWS EC2 + Nginx + Puma

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, amazon-ec2, puma

Deploying my ruby on rails on aws ec2 instance for the first time by using [Deploy Ruby on Rails on AWS EC2](https://gleecus.com/blog/a-quick-guide-to-deploy-rails-5-2-application-on-aws-ec2/). All setup is done but url still  can’t be reached and refused to connect. There are no logs in nginx error and access.

Here is my nginx

```
upstream app {
# Path to Puma SOCK file, as defined previously
  server unix:/home/ubuntu/peatio/shared/sockets/puma.sock fail_timeout=0;
}
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  root /home/ubuntu/peatio/public;
  index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
  server_name domain.tld www.domain.tld;
  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app;
  location @app {
    proxy_pass http://app;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    access_log /home/ubuntu/peatio/log/nginx.access.log;
    error_log /home/ubuntu/peatio/log/nginx.error.log;
  }
  location ~* ^/assets/ {
     # Per RFC2616 - 1 year maximum expiry
     expires 1y;
     add_header Cache-Control public;
     add_header Last-Modified "";
     add_header ETag "";
     break;
  }
  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

and here is my puma.rb

```
# Change to match your CPU core count
workers 2

# Min and Max threads per worker
threads 1, 6

app_dir = File.expand_path("../..", __FILE__)
shared_dir = "#{app_dir}/shared"

# Default to production
rails_env = ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || "production"
environment rails_env

# Set up socket location
bind "unix://#{shared_dir}/shared/sockets/puma.sock"

# Logging
stdout_redirect "#{shared_dir}/log/puma.stdout.log", "#{shared_dir}/log/puma.stderr.log", true

# Set master PID and state locations
pidfile "#{shared_dir}/pids/puma.pid"
state_path "#{shared_dir}/pids/puma.state"
activate_control_app

on_worker_boot do
  require "active_record"
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect! rescue ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(YAML.load_file("#{app_dir}/config/database.yml")[rails_env])
end
```

I restart nginx multiple times also. But when I hit public IPV4 IP nothing happens and no logs in nginx access or errors.

Security Inbound Rules are like this
[image]

What I am missing in that? As the site still saying 
This site can’t be reached 52.71.252.50 refused to connect.

Comment: Are you sure that `unix://#{shared_dir}/sockets/puma.sock` and `unix:/home/ubuntu/peatio/shared/sockets/puma.sock` are the same paths? Is the 504 error being returned by your running nginx instance? Are your security policies set to allow the inbound HTTP connection?

Comment: @anothermh thank you reply. Yes i have inbound policies... i update that question also

Comment: I suggest tweaking your nginx to [reply with a string](https://serverfault.com/a/491817/235711), then ensure nginx is starting and listening, and then ensure you can reach nginx. Simplify your problem until you can connect successfully.

Comment: @anothermh thank you...one step closer now ...
but now it gives a timeout error

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61836361/nginx-time-out-while-reading-response-header-from-upstream-xxx-sockets-puma-so